Fedora - Migrate root filesystem to new drive / partition
I need a quick bit of help. I've migrated my /root and /home directory off a BTRFS partition to and EXT4 partition, because, for some strange reason .. BTRFS always fail! .. However, now that the EXT4 has the /home and /root directory, it won't boot.
I have updated grub2.conf and fstab to use the new drive UUID, but I can't figure out how to update the initramfs, since ...
the OS in the /root directory is 6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64 and
the LiveCD I have is using 6.2.9-300.fc38.x86_64.
=====
I don't understand the directions as listed in this document
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-build-an-initramfs-using-dracut-on-linux
=====
FStab is pretty generic
UUID=[ ### ] / ext defaults 01

UUID=[ ### ] /home ext defaults 01

=====
The old FStab had
UUID=[ ### ] / btrfs subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 0 0

UUID=[ ### ] /home btrfs subvol=home,compress=zstd:1 0 0

=====
Grub.cfg
set kernelopts="root=UUID=[ ### ] ro

rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau

modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1

video=HDMI-0:D video=VGA-1-1:d "

=====
Have I missed something?
Do I need to run dracut --kver 6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
Do I need to issue a chroot command? And, if so where in the directory tree?
Should I give up the ghost and just start over? Much time will be lost in reconfiguring the OS.
Thoughts and prayers
=====
Update
Drives and Contents
 sda1 .. grub
 sda2 .. /root and /home

One problem that needed to be resolve was that sda2 cannot have both /root and /home in the same partition.  There are 2 options here ..
1 .. move the contents of /home to /root/home and then move the contents of /root to the root of the partition.
2 .. create 2 seperate partitions .. root and home
I took the later route to protect my data
sda1 .. grub
sda2 .. root
sda3 .. home
Now I can issue the mount commands correctly
cd /
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /run /mnt/run  

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

Then I change change the root with chroot
chroot /mnt /bin/bash

I grepped all the root mounts to make sure they were listed in mtab correctly
grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts
cat /etc/mtab

I then issued 2 versions of dracut.  The first confirms that it's working on the correct initramfs, and the 2nd one should update them.
dracut --regenerate-all
dracut -f --regenerate-all

Then I exited chroot and dismounted all the mounts, and confirmed using mount and lsblk.
exit

umount /mnt/boot 
umount /mnt/run  
umount /mnt/{proc,sys,dev}
umount /mnt

mount
lsblk 

And, finally shutdown the PC
reboot -p

However, upon reboot, the PC again attemped to locate the old BTRFS file system using the old UUID.  I don't know where this UUID could be hiding?  I went back through the process listed above, and issued
 lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.img

Only fstab.empty is listed
 0 Nov 15 16:00 etc/fstab.empty

So, I'm at a loss on what to change / do.
=====
Update 2
Since UUID's changed, you will need to run grub2's list and update commands. Make sure fstab lists the correct UUIDs
cat /etc/fstab

Use Grub to list the boot environments in the system
grub2-editenv - list

if you are still in chroot this shoudl list something like ...
grub2-editenv - list

saved_entry=a6a84281584b4fb69829b970ecb6d26b-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
boot_success=0
boot_indeterminate=0

otherwise it will list something like
boot_success=1

Now issue the update command .. 1 of the 2 will work.
update-grub2
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

Now confirm that the grub command actually updated the configuration file
cd /boot/loader/entries
ls -al

All entries should have today's date
cat a6a84281584b4fb69829b970ecb6d26b-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.conf

title Fedora Linux (6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64) 38 (MATE-Compiz)
version 6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
linux /vmlinuz-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
initrd /initramfs-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.img
options root=UUID=6bec82ae-4d47-4704-adfa-fd51dab23cc8 ro video=HDMI-0:D video=VGA-1-1:d 
grub_users $grub_users
grub_arg --unrestricted
grub_class fedora


Please note that I have successfully resolved this issue and will post my notes, once cleaned up.

This saga starts with a mix of technologies coming together and repeatedly
barfing.  These technologies for me are .. VirtualBox, Wine, and BTRFS
file systems ...  I'm not sure why, but whenever these 3 technologies
come together the BTRFS file system becomes corrupted.  But, let's set
aside why it barfs and focus on

What to do when it barfs.

If you want to move from a BTRFS to an EXT4 partition.

If you just want to move your linux operating system to a new hard
drive, because you need more drive space.


Note: where ever possible, I will try to provide the search terms needed
to allow you to find the right command to perform the function on your
version / distro of Linux.
!!! ALWAYS USE THE LATEST LIVE CD WHEN TROUBLESHOOTING BTRFS PARTITIONS !!!
!!! ALWAYS USE A LIVE CD THAT MATCHES YOUR CURRENT OS WHEN MANIPULATING INITRAMFS AND GRUB !!!
In this tutorial I will use LiveCD and terminal for most of the operations
to be executed here.  Whenever you see " > ", assume that I'm refering
to a terminal command, and I'm logged in as a super user.
> su
> whoami

root

Note: LiveCD does not require a password when logged in as a super user.
However, if your drive is encrypted, you will need to unlock it before
performing any operations on it.
=== CLI Commands we will use ===
`lsblk`, `ls`, `btrfsck`, `btrfs check`, `btrfs scrub`, `badblocks`, 
`mount -t btrfs`, `dmesg`, `mkfs.ext4`, `umount`, `chroot`, `fixfiles`, 
`touch /.autorelabel`, `blkid>`, `parted`, `e4label`, `df`, `dd`, `cp`,
`rsync`, `btrfs check`, `blkid`, `rm`, `cat`, `grep`, `vi`, `dracut`, 
`lsinitrd`, `grub2-editenv`, `update-grub2`, `grub2-mkconfig`, 
`dnf update`, `dnf remove`, `dnf install`, `rpm -Va`, `reboot -p`, 
`systemctl`, `dnf reinstall`

=== Drive UUIDs and Mappings ===
The first thing we want to do is find out where all our drives and
partitions have been mapped to.  `blkid`, and `ls` will tell us what 
the drive UUIDs are, for future reference, while the `lsblk` command 
tells where the drives / partitions have been mounted.

> blkid | grep /dev/sd  

/dev/sda1: UUID="d8755717-901c-47d0-9a72-d584f93eeb5c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="11ab6e7f-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="root" UUID="6bec82ae-4d47-4704-adfa-fd51dab23cc8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="11ab6e7f-02"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="home" UUID="8d30ac74-d8f5-472d-8fb2-c45988c4e89a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="11ab6e7f-03"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="924b405f-a7f0-e680-50b8-fff949d284db" UUID_SUB="4b7d64dc-5554-ea63-4d63-e20917d3d4bf" LABEL="fedora:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="f481e95f-01"
/dev/sdg1: UUID="4322e75a-cea4-4395-a3ab-8880ac64561b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5e91dae0-01"
> ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid

total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 180 May  4 11:40 .
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root 180 May  4 11:39 ..
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 May  4  2024 0ae2646a-8a22-4ab9-b4e9-1300348a52e3 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 May  4  2024 d8755717-901c-47d0-9a72-d584f93eeb5c -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 May  4  2024 6bec82ae-4d47-4704-adfa-fd51dab23cc8 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 May  4  2024 8d30ac74-d8f5-472d-8fb2-c45988c4e89a -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 May  4  2024 2023-04-13-22-14-25-00 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 May  4  2024 EBE8-26A4 -> ../../sdf2
> lsblk -l

NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS  LABEL
sda       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda2    8:3    0   1.8T  0 part  /
sdb       8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0   1.8T  0 part
└─md0   9:0    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /Data
sdf       8:0    0     1G  0 disk
└─sdf1    8:1    0     1G  0 part  /LiveCD
sdg       8:0    0     2T  0 disk
├─sdg1    8:1    0     1G  0 part  /mnt/boot        GRUB
├─sdg2    8:1    0   0.8T  0 part  /mnt/root        Root
└─sdg3    8:1    0     1T  0 part  /mnt/root/home   Home
OR
sdg       8:0    0     2T  0 disk
└─sdg1    8:1    0     1T  0 part  /mnt/sdg1        Backup
Let's review the partions before here

/dev/sda1 .. contains grub
/dev/sda2 .. contains the BTRFS with /root and /home subvolumes

/dev/sdb1 .. is a raid array with sdb, sdc, and sdd

/dev/sdf1 .. is the LiveCD

/dev/sdg .. is a backup drive where root and home will be copied to
/dev/sdg1 .. is the boot partition containing grub
/dev/sdg2 .. is the root partition containing the OS
/dev/sdg3 .. is the home partition containing the user directories

=== Preparing a Replacement / Backup Drive ===
It far faster and easier to use GParted GUI to partition, label, and 
format a new drive.  However, if you choose, use the commands here to
walk through the process manually.

> parted --list
> parted /dev/sdg
    > mklabel msdos # or gpt
    > print
    > mkpart primary EXT4 0 2T
    > print
    > set 1 boot off
    > quit
    
To label the drive
> e4label /dev/sdg1 Backup 

to format the drive
> mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdg

To create a mount point
> mkdir -p /mnt/sdg1 

To mount the drive
> mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt/sdg1 

To view drive/partition sizes
> df -hT 

=== Cloning the Drive ===
If you don't feel comfortable doing a destructive operation on your
hard drive, then perform a block level copy of the partition to 
another drive first.

To duplicate the partition to a new drive, use `dd`. Short for
Disk Duplicate

> dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdg bs=64K conv=noerror,sync

if .. means the input partition
of .. means the output partition
bs .. is the size of the chucks you want to read and write
        larger chucks mean faster service
        smaller chucks means better quality data
conv .. 

=== Recover your BTRFS file system ===
!!! ALWAYS USE THE LATEST LIVE CD WHEN TROUBLESHOOTING BTRFS PARTITIONS !!!
Initially, GParted GUI can be used to recover the BTRFS partition.  
Where possible, use the latest LiveCD OS when asking GParted to 
recover a BTRFS partition, as it has the latest methods to reconstruct 
the BTRFS tree.

If possible, store any reports that BTRFS generates to a seperate
drive. GParted, used to ask you to send these reports to them, but
it seems that they are no longer interested.

If GParted can't restore your hard drive to a usable state, switch
to terminal and attempt the recovery.

=====

Confirm that the drive has no physical issues by using `badblocks`.  
The command below will only do a verify, not a destructive 
write / read operation.

> badblocks -v [PARTITION]
> badblocks -v /dev/sda2

When `badblocks` is finished, we can attempt to recover the BTRFS
partition, with `btrfs check`, and `btrfs check --repair`. 

Use `btrfs check` initially for a non-destructive report on what has 
happened.

> btrfs check [PARTITION]
> btrfs check /dev/sda2

Use `btrfs check --repair` for a destructive repair. This will touch 
the drive and attempt to repair it.  (If you don't feel comfortable
with this option yet, then perform a block level copy of the 
partition to another drive first.)

> btrfs check --repair /dev/sda2

Once the BTRFS tree has been fixed, you can mount the partition
and move the contents to a backup device.

=== Copying Data Out ===
For my purposes, I did not use /dev/sdg as a replacement drive. I used
it as a backup drive.  For that, I only had /dev/sdg1 which contained
sub directories /root and /home.  I chose this option, as I didn't
want to disturb grub in /dev/sda1.

In the Linux distro that I use, the root and home folders are 
seperated into 2 sub volumes in the BTRFS partition.  What this
means, or how to think about this from a directory perspective, 
is that the BTRFS has created two folders .. root and home .. 
However, be careful with this perspective, since linux requires 
these directories .. root and home .. to be either merged into 1 tree 
or copied to seperate partitions when migrated to EXT4.  

For the backup process, I choose to create 1 partition on /dev/sdg1 to 
backup all the data to.  When that was complete, I choose then to 
create 2 partitions on /dev/sda, labeled "root" and "home", 

    /dev/sda2 .. root
    /dev/sda3 .. home

to restore the backed up folders to.

The other option for the restore is to create 1 large partition, and
the restore the contents of the /mnt/sdg1/root to /mnt/sda2 first, then 
restore /mnt/sdg1/home to /mnt/sda2/home

For this process, we will use `rsync`

Note: you can use copy `cp -a [SRC] [DEST]`, but you will lose the 
SELinux labels, and it won't give you a progress report.

> rsync --progress [SRC] [DEST]
> rsync --info=progress2 [SRC] [DEST] 

> mkdir -p /mnt/sda2
> mkdir -p /mnt/sdg1

To copy root and home as seperate directories to sdg1

> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
> mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt/sdg1

If mount /dev/sda2 throughs an error use `dmesg` to see what happened.
Unfortuantely, I don't remember what my BTRFS threw, but with a bit
of quick searching I was able to sort it out.

> dmesg

> rsync --progress /mnt/sda2/root /mnt/sdg1
> rsync --progress /mnt/sda2/home /mnt/sdg1

To copy root and home to seperate partitions

> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sda2
> mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt/sdg1
> mount /dev/sdg2 /mnt/sdg2

> rsync --progress /mnt/sda2/root/* /mnt/sdg1
> rsync --progress /mnt/sda2/home/* /mnt/sdg2

Once the contents have been copied out, you can swap the drives
or reformat the existing drive with a set of EXT4 partitions
for root and home, and copy the data back.

=== Updating Grub ===
!!! ALWAYS USE A LIVE CD THAT MATCHES YOUR CURRENT OS WHEN MANIPULATING INITRAMFS AND GRUB !!!
Once the partitions have the data, you are ready to tell Grub
where to look to start the OS.  This is known as updating Grub and
Updating the `initramfs`.

One mistake that most people make, is mounting /dev/sda1 and making
edits to grub directly. !!! DONT DO THIS !!!  Grub will make the
necessary changes to /dev/sda1.

Since all the drive and parition UUID's have changed, you will need
to relist them gain.

> blkid | grep /dev/sd
> ls -lha /dev/disk/by-uuid
> lsblk -l

If you followed any of the steps in copying the data out of a BTRFS 
partiton, make sure that /mnt is empty.

> cd /mnt
> rm { sda2, sdg1, sdg2 }

The next steps map the partitions to the /mnt directory and prepare
it for OS manipulation.

> cd /
> mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
> mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
> mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
> mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
> mount --bind /run /mnt/run  
> mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot

To configure your network while in chroot

> cp -L /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf

Enter `chroot`

=== ENTER Change Root ===
Do not exit `chroot` until you are explicitly told to in this script
otherwise, the commands you issue will affect LiveCD.

> chroot /mnt /bin/bash

Confirm that the `mtab` file to has all drives listed

> grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts
> cat /etc/mtab

Or

> grep -v rootfs /proc/mounts > /etc/mtab

Make sure the `fstab` file has the drives that should be auto-mounted
`vi` is a text editor

> cat /etc/fstab
> vi /etc/fstab

UUID=d8755717-901c-47d0-9a72-d584f93eeb5c /boot  ext4 defaults 1 2
UUID=6bec82ae-4d47-4704-adfa-fd51dab23cc8 /      ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=8d30ac74-d8f5-472d-8fb2-c45988c4e89a /home  ext4 defaults 0 1
List the `initramfs` found in the boot partition. You may need the
versions of the OS, if you have to run dracut on a different
PC to regenerate the initramfs.

> ls /boot | grep initramfs
initramfs-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.img

Regenerate your image file with `dracut`. The first command makes
sure you are hitting the right images. The second command will 
overwrite them.

> dracut --regenerate-all
> dracut -f --regenerate-all

Use `lsinitrd` to make sure the files are correct. It's not a necessary
step, but I was trying to see if `fstab` had been copied into the
image, and if so, did it contain the drive mappings.

> lsinitrd /boot/initramfs-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.img

!!! DO NOT EXIT chroot, just yet !!!

=== Update Grub ===
Since drive / partition UUID's changed, you will need to run grub2's 
list and update commands make sure grub matches `fstab`

> cat /etc/fstab

Use Grub to list the boot environments in the system

> grub2-editenv - list

saved_entry=a6a84281584b4fb69829b970ecb6d26b-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
boot_success=0
boot_indeterminate=0
Note: if you only see this (boot_success=1), you exited `chroot`. 
You can re-enter `chroot` by issueing the command above.

boot_success=1
Now issue the update 1 of the 2 commands below. 
They do the same thing ...

> update-grub2
> grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

Now confirm that the grub command actually updated the configuration 
file.

> cd /boot/loader/entries
> ls -al 

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  326 May  4 11:50 a6a84281584b4fb69829b970ecb6d26b-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.conf
All entries should have today's date

> cat a6a84281584b4fb69829b970ecb6d26b-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.conf

title Fedora Linux (6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64) 38 (MATE-Compiz)
version 6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
linux /vmlinuz-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64
initrd /initramfs-6.8.4-100.fc38.x86_64.img
options root=UUID=6bec82ae-4d47-4704-adfa-fd51dab23cc8 ro video=HDMI-0:D video=VGA-1-1:d
grub_users $grub_users
grub_arg --unrestricted
grub_class fedora
Make sure the UUID listed as root, matches the device partiton 
/dev/sda1's UUID.

If you see quiet in the output, re-run update-grub2 and turn off quiet.
You will want to see any and all errors during the boot process to 
trouble shoot them.

One such error that can occur, is the system won't boot if the JournalCtl
fails to start.  This happens due to a SELinux issue.

!!! DO NOT EXIT chroot, just yet !!!

=== Updating SELinux ===
SELinux is the enhanced security system Linux uses to make sure 
roge programs can't touch files they aren't supposed to.  Sometimes
turning off the system can help you trouble shoot boot issues.

See the current status of the OS    

> sestatus

See if SE Linux is being enforced or not

> getenforce

Check SE Linux's configuration file

> cat /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
#    grubby --update-kernel ALL --args selinux=0
# To revert back to SELinux enabled:
#    grubby --update-kernel ALL --remove-args selinux
SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
To fix the files for SE Linux so that they are all labeled correctly
use `fixfiles` or `touch /.autorelabel`

> fixfiles onboot
> touch /.autorelabel

=== End Change Root ===
You can now safely exit `chroot`

> exit

Dismount all the drive and partition mappings from above

> umount /mnt/boot 
> umount /mnt/run  
> umount /mnt/{proc,sys,dev}
> umount /mnt

Issue mount to determine if all the mounts have been dismounted

> mount
> lsblk -l

Shutdown the pc, either from CLI or from the LiveCD desktop

> reboot -p

=== Reboot ===
As your computer reboots it will run into errors. Remember, though,
one of the operations running in the background is `fixfiles`.
Let this operation complete before you begin any trouble shooting.

If you see that the JournalCtl has failed, this is becuase `fixfiles`
has not completed its job, and JournalCtl cant access its files
due to SELinux.

If the problem persists, turn off SELinux as instructed above.

Another reported issue that could come up is the `machine-id` 
mismatch between /etc/machine-id and /var/lib/dbus/machine-id. 
You could try resetting them, but as I found out, the ID's contained
in these files match those in Grub, and many other locations. So,
avoid them until you cant.

> systemd-firstboot --root=/mnt --setup-machine-id
or 
> systemd-machine-id-setup


If problems persist, and you need to use the LiveCD to go back
into the OS to fix things, follow the `Enter Change Root` and 
`Exit Change Root` steps.

=== Post Clean Up ===
Once your OS is up and running, you should update it immediately 
and verify that all packages are functional.

> dnf update
> rpm -Va

If `dnf` doesn't update the kernal, then issue `dnf reinstall` and 
execute `dracut` again.  You won't need to use `chroot` as you are
in the system you want to change.

> dnf reinstall
> dracut --regenerate-all
> dracut -f --regenerate-all

After the update reboot

> reboot -p

The next thing I did was remove VirtualBox

> dnf remove VirtualBox-\*
> dnf list installed | grep -i VirtualBox
> dnf list installed | grep -i vbox

Make sure `systemctl` says that anything vbox or VirtualBox is 
stopped.

> systemctl | grep -i VirtualBox
> systemctl | grep -i vbox

Reboot

> reboot -p

You can re-install VirtualBox if needed at this point.

> dnf install VirtualBox

=== References ===
=== Problems Booting into EXT4 ===
F40 not boot after upgrade 39->40
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?332468-F40-not-boot-after-upgrade-39-gt-40&highlight=initramfs
Kernel upgrade isssue
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?332442-Kernel-upgrade-isssue&highlight=initramfs
Problems booting with an ext4 root filesystem
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=72844
=== GParted ===
GParted forum
http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewforum.php?id=2
=== Disk Cloning / Duplicating ===
Using DD for disk cloning
https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning
How to Clone a Partition or Hard drive in Linux
https://www.tecmint.com/clone-linux-partitions/
dd-ArchWiki
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dd
=== Partitioning Drives ===
linux mount command syntax
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html
Creating a Disk Partition in Linux
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-a-disk-partition-in-linux/
How to Create a New Ext4 File System (Partition) in Linux
https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-ext4-file-system-partition-in-linux/
How to set or change boot partition flag on Linux
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-or-change-boot-partition-flag-on-linux
Set Bootable Partition Command Line
Set Bootable Partition Command Line
=== BTRFS ===
BTRFS error when using gparted?
https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/17od8g0/btrfs_error_when_using_gparted/
Mount can't find device in /etc/fstab
https://askubuntu.com/questions/771473/mount-cant-find-device-in-etc-fstab
How to recover from BTRFS errors
https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018769
Btrfs - ArchWiki
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/btrfs
Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/nxdbar/wrong_fs_type_bad_option_bad_superblock/
How do I recover a BTRFS partition that will not mount?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/157917/how-do-i-recover-a-btrfs-partition-that-will-not-mount
convert BTRFS to Ext4
https://askubuntu.com/questions/36252/how-can-i-convert-my-root-partition-from-btrfs-to-ext4
=== Change Root - What is it? ===
chroot
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot
what is chroot?
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=what+is+chroot%3F
=== Update initramfs ===
How to run update-initramfs from bootable usb?
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/dracut-generating-initramfs/37346/10
How to restore deleted files in /boot? (vmlinuz missing, system does not boot)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/696409/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-boot-vmlinuz-missing-system-does-not-boot/696653#696653
How to regenerate intrramfs on boot partition from live dvd
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?311425-How-to-regenerate-intrramfs-on-boot-partition-from-live-dvd
regenerate initramfs after moving boot partition
https://superuser.com/questions/901162/regenerate-initramfs-after-moving-boot-partition
How to use initramfs-tools instead of dracut? #1000
https://github.com/systemd/mkosi/issues/1000
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/dracut-generating-initramfs/37346/10
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/dracut-generating-initramfs/37346/10
=== Update Grub ===
Grub2/Setup
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup
What is the correct command to use to update grub after editing the kernel’s menu entries?
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/what-is-the-correct-command-to-use-to-update-grub-after-editing-the-kernels-menu-entries/77260
After changing a system disk partition, system won't boot, goes into "Dracut Emergency Shell"; how do I get it to boot?
https://serverfault.com/questions/1031328/after-changing-a-system-disk-partition-system-wont-boot-goes-into-dracut-eme
How to build an initramfs using Dracut on Linux
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-build-an-initramfs-using-dracut-on-linux
Help with dracut(8) and/or adding device path in /boot/initramfs after O/S migration
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?294196-Help-with-dracut(8)-and-or-adding-device-path-in-boot-initramfs-after-O-S-migration
regenerate initramfs after moving boot partition
https://superuser.com/questions/901162/regenerate-initramfs-after-moving-boot-partition
=== SE Linux ===
enable permissive SELinux mode
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=enable+permissive+SELinux+mode+
Permanent changes in SELinux states and modes
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/selinux-changing-states-and-modes/
=== Update DNF ===
Have DNF check installed package?
https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/nqymdc/have_dnf_check_installed_package/
Using RPM to Verify Installed Packages
http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-verify-what-to-verify.html#S2-RPM-VERIFY-A-OPTION
=== End of File ===
